# Arabic regex giving TypeError

Tags: python, regex, arabic

I have this simple regex:

```
    text = re.sub("[إأٱآا]", "ا", text)
```

However, I get this (Python 2.7) error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I'm a regex newbie,  I imagine this is a simple thing to fix, but I'm
not sure how? Thanks.

Comment: It must have something to do with encoding, Have you made sure it's UTF8?

Comment: Arabic is RTL, which is throwing you off; Python doesn't see your code anything like how it's displayed here.

Comment: For example, that second `[` is actually a `]` that's being displayed mirrored, and most of what looks like the second string is actually in the first string and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define all your strings as `unicode` and don't forget to add the encoding line in the header of the file:

```
#coding: utf-8

import re

text = re.sub(u"[إأٱآا]", u"ا", u"الآلهة")

print text
```

To get:

```
الالهة
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` expects regex as first parameter. You need to escape the left bracket in your patterns. Use `\[` instead of `[`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't fit this in the comments section. There is nothing wrong in the re.sub as far as I understand. Because if you code the chars back to unicode you get the below verbatim.

```
text = re.sub("[\u0625\u0623\u0671\u0622\u0627]", "\u0627", text)
```

1. Because it is arabic, remember it is right to left, the visuals are a bit jumbled that's all.
2. It is actually trying to replace a set of chars with one char.
3. Although why would one replace `\u0627` with `\u0627`, I do not know.

The issue I believe is with `text`. If you can do `print(text)`, then we can see if there are any chars in it that belong to `"[إأٱآا]"` == `"[\u0625\u0623\u0671\u0622\u0627]"`

*Just a quip the `\u0627` is the smallest vertical line on the left ;-)*

Little help in understanding what it actually is use(just copy the **whole** statement in the question and do the below)

```
for x in mystr: print(x + '-' + str(ord(x)))
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0627/index.htm

**EDITED**

```
>>> re.sub(myset,myrep,text)
u'\u0627\u0627\u0627abc'
>>> res=re.sub(myset,myrep,text)
>>> res
u'\u0627\u0627\u0627abc'
>>> myrep
u'\u0627'
>>> myset
u'[\u0625\u0623\u0671\u0622\u0627]'
>>> text
u'\u0625\u0623\u0623abc'
>>> print(res)
اااabc
>>> print(myrep)
ا
>>> print(myset)
[إأٱآا]
>>> print(text)
إأأabc
>>>
```

So in essence All Works Well and the error is else where.

I think reproduced the error that is occurring elsewhere and here it is

```
>>> print(u'\u0625'+ord(u'\u0625'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

Cheers!

Comment: in essence the error is somewhere where you are trying to add an `int` to `str`. And int is >128 thus it complains about buffer.

Comment: @BenderRodriguez were you able to find out where you were adding `str` and `int`? Let me know if anything I wrote was not clear, I can better my writing.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I eventually did it:

```
sText = re.sub(ur"[\u0625|\u0623|\u0671|\u0622|\u0627]", ur"\u0627", sText)
```

Thank you all for your help.